# Getting Percentage based on records SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Greetings I have this table `Evaluation.Grade` with these records:

```
Name Percentage
---------------
B       40
C       20
A       20
D       10
A+      10
```

And I am storing my given data after assessment to this table `Evaluation.Assessment` :

```
Total Grade 
------------
117   A+
2     D
```

What I am trying to achieve here is getting what percentage of which grade I have stored so based on that i create a limitation back within my code. Something like this:

```
Grade Percentage
------------
A+    50
D     50
A     0
B     0
C     0
```

But right now using this query I get something like this:

```
Select 
    aa.Grade, (Count(aa.Grade) * 100 / 
                    (Select Count(*) 
                     From Evaluation.Assessment 
                     Where SupervisorId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')) as Percentage
From 
    Evaluation.Assessment aa
Where
    aa.SupervisorId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
Group By 
    Grade


 Grade Percentage
 ----------------
 A+      50
 D       50
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What do the two tables have to do with each other?  What happened to the rest of the grades?  How are the "50"s calculated?

Comment: @GordonLinoff apologies let me clear it up. i have this dynamic feature that creates new grades, every grade has a name within this table. now part 2, when i insert data within my second table i make sure the grade is within those names that i already inserted before. now part 3 what i need is to know what grade has what percentage of data base on my records of second table. i got this right with what i tried "query above". however it only returns Grade/Percentage those records that are within second table,

Comment: @GordonLinoff  this creates a problem unless i insert every Grade within second table i wont be able to get others grades percentage. ofc they are 0 but i was thinking if i can get them as list would make my day.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i think i need more sleep... >_>

Comment: `OUTER JOIN` is often the answer to a question of wanting something that corresponds to nothing, e.g. `select * from Evaluation.Grade as EG left outer join Evaluation.Assessment as EA on EA.Grade = EG.Grade ...;`. I still don't have a clue as to what is going on in your question + comments. Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: @HABO it happens when u don't sleep for 48hours =/ i got it fixed tho. stupid approach it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your requirement right, your can achieve this easily with windowed aggregation (i.e. using [OVER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017))

```
CREATE TABLE grade 
  ( 
     NAME       VARCHAR(10), 
     percentage INT 
  ); 

CREATE TABLE assessment 
  ( 
     grade VARCHAR(10), 
     total INT 
  ); 

INSERT INTO grade 
VALUES ('B', 40), ('C', 20), ('A', 20), ('D', 10), ('A+', 10); 

INSERT INTO assessment 
VALUES ('A+', 117), ('D', 2), ('A', 65);

SELECT g.NAME                                     AS grade, 
       Count(a.total) 
         OVER( 
           partition BY a.grade) * 100 / Count(a.total) 
                                           OVER() AS percentage 
FROM   grade g 
       LEFT JOIN assessment a 
              ON g.NAME = a.grade 
ORDER  BY percentage DESC;
```

And this is how your result will look like:

[image]

Online executable of the [query](http://rextester.com/SIZZ23394).